# Python: how to merge two dataframes with different size?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, `df` and `df1`. The first one contains all the information about all the possible combination of a dataset while the second one is just a subset without the information.

```
df

x   y   distance    
0   1      4
0   2      3
0   3      2
1   2      2
1   3      5
2   3      1

df1

x   y       
1   3      
2   3      
2   3
```

I would like to merge `df` and `df1` in order to have the following:

```
df1

x   y   distance    
1   3      5
2   3      1
2   3      1
```

Comment: @RexLow Although there is a slight difference that here it's not necessary the indexes do match but the columns x,y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the merge command

```
df.merge(df1, left_on=['x','y'], right_on=['x','y'], how='right')
```

Here you're merging the `df` on the left with `df1` on the right using the columns `x` and`y` as merging criteria and keeping only the rows that are present in the right dataframe.

You can read more about merging and joining dataframes [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: Not OP but getting through the same kind of problems. Would you care to explain why you need to include `right_on=['x','y']` please? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101